# How to extract raw values for comparison or manipulation from Gremlin (Tinkerpop)

Tags: groovy, graph, titan, tinkerpop3

I know I'm missing something obvious here. I'm trying to extract values from TitanDB using Gremlin in order to compare them within Groovy.

```
graph = TinkerFactory.createModern()
g = graph.traversal(standard())
markoCount = g.V().has('name','marko').outE('knows').count()
lopCount = g.V().has('name','lop').outE('knows').count()
if(markoCount > lopCount){
// Do something
}
```

But apparently what I'm actually (incorrectly) doing here is comparing traversal steps which obviously won't work:

> Cannot compare org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.dsl.graph.DefaultGraphTraversal with value '[TinkerGraphStep(vertex,[name.eq(marko)]), VertexStep(OUT,[knows],edge), CountGlobalStep]' and org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.dsl.graph.DefaultGraphTraversal with value '[TinkerGraphStep(vertex,[name.eq(lop)]), VertexStep(OUT,[knows],edge), CountGlobalStep]'

I'm having the same issue extracting values from properties for use in Groovy as well. I didn't see anything in the [docs](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.1.1-incubating/reference/#graph) indicating how to set raw values like this.

What is needed to return actual values from Gremlin that I can use later in my Groovy code?

Comment: Don't you need `.path()` on the end of `.count()` to get a list of the counts for each path?

Comment: I think what I need is `next()` to get the actual value. That seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out, I needed `next()`:

```
graph = TinkerFactory.createModern()
g = graph.traversal(standard())
markoCount = g.V().has('name','marko').outE('knows').count().next()
lopCount = g.V().has('name','lop').outE('knows').count().next()
if(markoCount > lopCount){
// Do something
}
```